# Git auto generate pull requests on main branch while I push new commits

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

IDE: VSCode

Extension: Gitlens

SO: Linux mint cinnamon 20.1

I'm not sure the problem is related to those technologies but here is my problem.
I'm working in a team on a private repository on GitHub with different branches.
Actually, we're working only on one branch (not main), and every time I commit and push some new code GitHub alert me to "compare & create a pull request" from my branch to main like that: [that's just an example found on the web](https://marcolombardo.com/blog/images/github-5p.png)
Before, this change of workflow, simple commit/push operations goes fluid without problems.
Also, this happens only to me not to my colleagues so it should be something with my configs. I also tried to delete my local repo and clone again but nothing changed.

Many thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: This should be vscode 100% because I tried right now to "git push" from the terminal and everything goes without problems. Any one know how to fix that on vscode?

Comment: PRs aren't actually being auto-generated, right? I think GitHub is simply offering you the option to create a PR with one button click if you want to. If you don't want to create one, maybe you can just ignore that suggestion? Or, are you just more curious as to *why* this seems to happen in some situations and not others?

Comment: Thanks for the alswer. The second option also how to stop it...As I said before nothing of this happens in past.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has the concept of a *default branch*, which in the repository you're working in is `main`.  Any time you push to a branch other then the default branch, GitHub will suggest you open a pull request, since that's a thing people often want to do.

If you don't want to do that in this case, just ignore the message, and keep working as before.  If you do nothing, no pull request will be opened, and nothing will change.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but Github still alert about the compare & pull request.
I can't let the repo of my company with that alert. Also, I can't always create requests and deny to make alert disappear.

Comment: It's to make it easy for you to do a pull request if you want.  If you don't want to, just ignore it.  You don't have to if you don't want to, and there's no downsides to not doing it.